# Update controller from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have brands and models (models belong to brands)

```
<ul>
    <li droppable ng-repeat="brand in vm.brands">
        <h1>{{ brand.name }}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li id="model.brand" draggable ng-repeat="model in vm.models | filter: { brand: brand }">
                <div model="model">{{model.name}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I added some drag and drop functionality in the directive to move models between brands.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('draggable', draggable)
        .directive('droppable', droppable);

    draggable.$inject = [];
    droppable.$inject = [];

    function draggable() {

        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

                elem.bind('dragenter dragover', function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

                elem.attr('draggable', 'true');

                elem.on('dragstart', function(event) {
                    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id);
                });

            },

        };

        return directive;
    }

    function droppable() {

        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

                elem.bind('dragenter dragover dragleave drop', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

                elem.bind('drop', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
                    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

                });

            },

        };

        return directive;
    }

})();
```

**My question is:** when I drop the element. How can I update the model brand?

thank you.

Comment: You mean broadcast() in the directive? broadcast what? I can´t find the ¨new¨brand withing the directive

Answer (score 1):

You can call some function whenever there is drop event.

Like below.

JS file:

```
function droppable() {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            onDropEvent: "&"
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

             elem.bind('dragenter dragover dragleave drop', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            elem.bind('drop', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
                event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                scope.onDropEvent({data: data}); // calling onDropEvent function with passing selected data.                        
            });
        }
   };
   return directive;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<li droppable on-drop-event="callDropEvent(data)" ng-repeat="brand in vm.brands">
```

So in your controller you can create some function called **callDropEvent** with argument, so whenever drop event happens you can write whatever logic to change brand model.

Comment: really nice!! I was able to send the model back to the controller. but how can I know what is the ¨target¨ brand?

Comment: i think whenever you get "event" callback, in that you can have some value. or you can assign id of brand to h1 tag, so whenever u get event call back in that you have that id and then you can match it

Comment: Sorry I don´t get it. can you give me an example please? thank you